# Does VMWare Server run on a Windows 7 Host Machine?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, virtualhost, vmware-server

I'm currently running Vista Ultimate but I'm thinking about updating to Windows 7.  Vista was not supported a host systems with VMWare Server (free version).

**Question:  Does the latest version of the VMWare Server support Windows 7 has the host machine?**

Comment: Why not just look on vmware.com instead of asking here ?

Comment: It's not really described at the vmware server site or even in the vmware datasheet:
http://www.vmware.com/products/server/faqs.html

do you need the vmware server? the newest release of vmware workstation will run on windows 7

Comment: @gareth_bowles - As @grub explained this specific question was not answered on the www.vmware.com.  I assure you that I checked there first. Thx for your help :-)

Comment: @grub I wanted to use the vmware server since it was free instead of paying for the workstation product.  I would really like to run vmware server on a windows 7 host. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been running the latest VMWare Server (2.0.2-203138) on Windows 7 Ultimate for a couple of days now and see no difference to previous host OSs, haven't encountered any problems.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, VMWare player is free. The main downfall is that you can't make new VMs, but http://www.easyvmx.com/ will make the VM with settings for you. Just connect the ISO and go.

Comment: You can now make VMs in the new version, VMWare Player 3.0, which is still free.

Comment: Awesome! I don't really pay attention to their new offerings in desktop virtualization, so I missed that.

Comment: @MarkM thx for the alternative I didn't know that VMWARE Player now lets you create new VM's.  I would give you an up vote but I don't have enough points yet.

Answer (score 0):

Im using VMWare Server 1.0.9 with Windows 7 Ultimate and have a SLES Proxy running on that.
It works great!